# Do familiars get death saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, character-death

Do familiars summoned by the [*Find Familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell get to utilize [Death Saving Throws](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DeathSavingThrows), or do they die immediately when they reach 0 hit points?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### No, they just disappear.

[*Find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) states (PHB, pg. 240):

> When the familiar drops to 0 hit points, it disappears, leaving behind no physical form. It reappears after you cast this spell again.

It does not die, nor does it fall unconscious. It just *disappears*.